# Taking integer as parameter and returning an array

Tags: c++, arrays, return

I want to create a function that takes an integer as it's parameter and returns an array in C++. This is the pseudo-code I had in mind:

```
function returnarray(integer i)
{
    integer intarr[i];

    for (integer j = 0; j < i; j++) { intarr[j] = j; }

    return intarr;
}
```

I tried the common way of declaring returnarray as function* returning a pointer, but then I can't take an integer as my parameter. I also can't assign j to intarr[j]. I'd really like to avoid making a pointer to an int just so I could use the parameter.

Is there any way of doing this and being able to assign j to intarr[j] without making a pointer for it?

EDIT:

forgot to write that I want to avoid vectors. I use them only if I really have to! (my reasons are mine).

Thanks :D

Comment: This has nothing to do with function pointers, so I removed the tag.

Comment: You need to state your reasons for wishing to avoid vectors. A vector provides an obvious solution; answerers need to know what restrictions on potential solutions you are imposing.

Comment: @MisterSir: If you don't want to use vectors, then, well, you lie in a bed of your own making.

Comment: I just don't want to use vectors. Vectors are just an easy way out for such problems. If I want to actually learn something, I should try doing something without the obvious solution. I could use vectors, but then I wouldn't learn anything new. Don't get me wrong, I love vectors, but it's just that I think not using them for such a thing can improve my understanding of C++.

Comment: @MisterSir: If you want to improve your understanding of C++, you need to tackle a problem which has a solution that you don't already understand- for example, *implementing* vector. Solving easy problems with strange solutions won't improve your understanding of the language in any meaningful fashion.

Comment: Those strange solutions are the solutions which are going to help me implement a vector, which is why I need this "strange solution". It's also a matter of curiosity.

Comment: Why not just ask "how can I implement a vector replacement as a learning exercise?" rather than send everyone on a wild goose chase?

Comment: Because I don't have any problems with implementing a vector. It's only this particular issue. I wrote that I don't want to use vectors, so I don't see how I could have made it any clearer.

Comment: How about: "the reason I don't want to use a vector is that I am implementing a vector replacement as a learning exercise". That would have been clearer. I still don't understand what you are trying to do, though, as no part of the interface of vector requires you to have to return an array.

Comment: @MisterSir: "Just an easy way out"?!  Driving a car or taking public transit is "just an easy way out", I hope you walk across your country so you can "actually learn something" instead of getting things done.

Comment: @Charles I asked you guys not to give me solutions with vectors. So why do you insist on solving it with vectors? Why does it matter why I don't want to use them? Are you trying to "improve my programming habits" or stuff like that? I'm not an idiot, trust me, and I know when to use vectors. If I wrote that I don't want to, then I don't see the problem.

Comment: @MisterSir: Because doing resource management by hand is not idiomatic C++. Switching from `malloc` to `new` does not make you a C++ programmer, your code is basically still C.

Comment: It is important to know why you don't want to use a vector as the reasons that you don't want to use a vector may apply to other solutions. For example, return a `std::deque` instead is similarly inappropriate as would a solution to create a minimal vector replacement and return that instead (because that is what you are already trying to do). If you tell people what you are doing and why then they can help you without you needing to add more and more restrictions every time they come up with a solution that isn't appropriate for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use dynamic memory. Something like this

```
int* returnArray(int size) {
    int* array = new int[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        array[i] = i;
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to initialize the values in the array (as per posted pseudo-code) :)

Comment: -1 This is ungood because it teaches beginner to use raw pointers and `new` and `delete`, dealing manually with lifetimes. it just stops leaning for a long time because the beginner has to deal with mostly extraneous issues. then later the person has to unlearn all that stuff.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Learning how to use raw pointers is one of the most important skills a programmer can possibly have. I was taught pointers in week 3 at Digipen ( not that I immediately understood them)

Comment: @EnabrenTane: Learning how to use raw pointers is important, but they're not always the best starting point for a beginner. It's often better to learn how to use something like vector first, and then worry about how it's implemented internally.

Comment: The programmer will later have to use `delete` outside the function, correct?

Comment: @Maxpm yes. They have to save the return value and then later call delete on it when they are done.

Comment: When you say "when they are done," what really must be meant is "at some point between the moment the dynamically allocated object is no longer needed and the moment that you lose the ability to destroy it."  The problem is that doing that correctly is difficult, and it is almost impossible for a beginner who is unlikely to fully understand the C++ object model.  C++ provides facilities to manage object lifetimes for you and there are very, very few reasons not to take advantage of them.

Comment: Sheltering people from harsh realities is a difficult task. We all make our mistakes on the way to learning.

Comment: @Maxpm: No, `delete p` will result in undefined behavior. The array has to be released via `delete[] p`. What do you think is easier, teaching a beginner the usage of `std::vector` or the concept of undefined behavior?

Answer (score 10):

You can't return a stack-allocated array- it's going to go out of scope and the memory deallocated. In addition, C++ does not allow stack-allocated variable-length arrays. You should use a std::vector.

```
std::vector<int> returnarray(int i) {
    std::vector<int> ret(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) ret[j] = j;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: If you are comfortable with STL Vectors are great. If you are more familiar with C code my answer is more "old school"

its a matter of taste, each method has their pros and cons

Comment: +1 for the concise answer, though I'm wondering if there's any additional benefit to be had in returning a `const std::vector<int>`?

Comment: @EnabrenTane: No, that's not actually true at all. Your method has a gigantic list of program-ruining cons. Like, no bounds checking, no exception safety, no automatic release, no semantic enforcement. The only advantage it has is cross-compiler/cross-language link ability. And every C++ programmer should be comfortable with the STL vector. The incredible failings of that answer are the entire reason that these C++ concepts exist. @ig2r: No, there's none to be had.

Comment: C "Speed first and safety if there is time"

Comment: @Enabren: Except you could have both speed and safety with a vector.

Answer (score 5):

your code isn't even near valid c++ so i assume you're total beginner

use `std::vector`

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> yourFunction( int n )
{
    std::vector<int>  result;
    for( int i = 0;  i < n;  ++i )
    {
        result.push_back( i );
    }
    return result;
}
```

Disclaimer: code untouched by compilers' hands.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: It's just pseudo-code meant to show what I'm trying to do. I could just use a vector, but I also forgot to write that I want to avoid vectors. It's possible to use them, but it will just make my code more complicated because I'm in need to approach arrays directly. Thanks anyways though.

Comment: @MisterSir: Using `std::vector` will make your code simpler, not more complicated. For a start it is not possible to have a function that returns an array so you have to do _something_ else. Returning a `std::vector` is the simplest alternative in almost every respect.

Comment: Consider result.reserve(n) . Otherwise push_back will have poor performance for large values of n. Depending on the implementation usually vectors grow by about 1.5 to 2x. meaning you will have to reallocate and memcpy repeatedly.

Comment: @EnabrenTane: there is no need to use `reserve` here, because the desired size can be simply be used as constructor argument (see @DeadMG's answer). I chose to illustrate `push_back` because the OP could learn something useful from that. I chose to not illustrate premature optimization because the OP would learn the Wrong Thing from that. But as it turned out, the OP didn't learn from any of the `std::vector` answers. So, the effort to compose good answer was in vain.

Comment: @EnabrenTane: also, as illustration of what I mean by "learning the Wrong Thing", the possible poor performance is for *small* values of `n`, not for large ones. You've learned something wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Two remarks, before using the excellent @DeadMG 's solution:

1) You never want to avoid vectors. If `v` is a vector, and you really want a pointer, you can always have a pointer to the first element by writing `&v[0]`.

2) You can't return an array. You will return a pointer to a fresh memory zone that you'll have to delete once finished with it. Vectors are only arrays with an automatic deletion facility, so you won't leak memory.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'd particularly recommend this approach in general, but you can use templates to do this without resorting to dynamic memory allocation. Unfortunately you can't return arrays from functions, so you'd need to return a struct with the array inside.

```
template <int N>
struct int_array_type {
    int ints[N];
};

template <int N>
int_array_type<N> returnarray() {
    int_array_type<N> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        a.ints[i] = i;
    return a;
}
```

...

```
int_array_type<10> u = returnarray<10>();
std::copy(u.ints, u.ints+sizeof(u.ints)/sizeof(u.ints[0]),
    std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```